# Is there a way to sign my WinForms program for free?

Tags: c#, winforms, signature

I've just finished creating a WinForms application for my company. Everything works fine, but when my co-workers run the program, they need to provide the domain administrator password, which one of those co-workers doesn't have access to. How could I sign the program, or make an exception somewhere on their computers so that they don't have to use the admin login to use it? I'm not going to pay for a certificate.

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2015. The computers are running windows 8.1.

Thanks

Comment: It's not you whi pays that certificate but the company should pay for that.

Comment: I'm an apprentice working in an IT position, not a software dev. I made this as a little side-project during work downtime to speed up one part of a product-upload process. Getting management to pay a lot of money for this is out of the question.

Comment: @stuartd It's a locked down corporate environment - many corporations do not allow users to install software as it's an operational risk.

Comment: @toadflakz I understand that, I was curious as to why they needed the **domain** admin password, and what difference signing the app would make. In a locked down corporate environment the domain admin password should be a guarded secret..

Comment: @stuartd It is possible to add a trusted publisher exception for installation rights afaik. So allow, for example, anything published and signed by Microsoft to be installed, but reject Google. Domain admin is the highest level of rights required and on an AD-based Windows network, the typical user who is allowed to install stuff. It is possible to configure machines to disallow local admin access.

Comment: @toadflakz thanks. It's been a while and I had forgotten the joys (!?) of working in a locked-down environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yes. You can have your AD Administrator issue and load a certificate as part of the Global User Policy on your network.

**Long answer:**

You need to use the right type of certificate for signing of the application manifest, if, for example, you are planning to use ClickOnce to deploy the application. (This is much easier to do than using SignTool.exe to sign a binary).

Your AD Admin will need to setup your PDC as a Root CA for your network. This Root CA will issue the certificate and the certificate will need to be included in the default network profile of your target users on the locked down network environment.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to mark this as the answer if it works out for you.